# Execute python file existing inside image with Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, groovy

I have an Image A, which has a python file "main.py". I want to know how I can use Jenkins to run that file from a different pipeline. I want to use Jenkins to go inside that image and then run that file which is inside Image A.

I tried using .withRun but I don't think I'm doing this right.

```
docker.image(ImageA).withRun() {
    sh "main.py ${parameters to pass}"
}
```

When I run it like this, it executes the local main.py that I have and executes that inside the container which isn't what I want. I want to execute the main.py that is already inside the container and pass in parameters.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the `inside` command (see [more info](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#advanced-usage-with-scripted-pipeline)) which will execute your shell command inside the docker image using the local image files as you want. Something like: `docker.image(ImageA).inside() {...}`

Comment: @NoamHelmer when I use the .inside() and I use a sh command and pass in my main.py, it's looking for main.py from within the current build and not within Image B. I heard a better way to do this would be to somehow use build artifacts to access files from another workspace (imageB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out the solution. In the ImageA pipeline, I added the 'main.py' to the artifacts and then in ImageA, I cloned 'main.py' and executed it.

ImageA:

```
always {
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'main.py', onlyIfSuccessful: true
    }
```

Current pipeline:

```
sh "curl {url to imageA artifact}/main.py -o main.py"
docker.image(ImageA).inside {

    sh "python main.py "

}
```